# W3C Validation Failed, llegal character in path segment: space is not allowed, Even though there are no spaces

Tags: html, w3c

Hello I am trying to figure out why is it telling me that the spaces is not allowed even thought from the HTML you can see that there is no spaces in the img

```
 <img src="media/Review 1.jpg" alt="Review" class="Reviewphoto">
```

W3C Validation results:
[image]

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The space is right there, between `Review` and `1`:

```html
 <img src="media/Review█1.jpg" alt="Review" class="Reviewphoto">
                       ^ here is the space
```

Do you see it now?

You need to [encode](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP) it as `%20` so the URL becomes `media/Review%201.jpg`:

```html
 <img src="media/Review%201.jpg" alt="Review" class="Reviewphoto">
```